# Ajax Post method is not sending multiple data to php

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have these two buttons

```
<div id="rating-votes">
        <button class="btn like">Like</button>
        <span class="likes">0</span>
        <button class="btn dislike">Dislike</button>
        <span class="dislikes">0</span>
</div>
```

I am trying to pass data using ajax call but its not sending the data to php

its script here

```
$('#rating-votes').likeDislike({
    reverseMode: true,
    disabledClass: 'disable',
    click: function (value, l, d, event) {
        var likes = $(this.element).find('.likes');
        var dislikes =  $(this.element).find('.dislikes');
        $.ajax({
            url: '',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'likes=' + likes + '&dislikes=' + dislikes,
            success: function (data) {
                likes.text(parseInt(likes.text()) + l);
                dislikes.text(parseInt(dislikes.text()) + d);
            }
       });
    }
});
```

May anyone do some correction

Comment: What is the error? Have you checked the browser console ?

Comment: Try using JSON format, `data: {"likes": likes, "dislikes": dislikes},`.

Comment: @nurdyguy i tried it, but it did not work

Comment: Actually, you have bigger problems than just that...  First off, your `var dislikes =  $(this.element).find('.dislikes');` is going to return an array of jQuery elements (because there are multiple items with class `dislike`.  I'm guessing you really just want the number in the `span.dislikes` so change the jQuery to target that, something like this `var dislikes =  $(this.element).find('span.dislikes').text();`  Step through the code and make sure the values are correct.

Comment: Correction on my last comment, didnt see the `s` on the class name.  Anyways, what I wrote there should still work.

Comment: @nurdyguy exactly i am gonna show the number of dislikes in `span.dislikes`

Comment: @nurdyguy its still not working, also, now the number of likes and dislikes are not increased or decreased on clicking like or dislike

Comment: Can you please put your console's output, also your network http behaviour.  There you can check ho'w your http packet is being created, also the data that is being set. The most probably is that you get a 400 error code 'Bad request'. If you use these tools you can fix your error pretty easily.

Comment: @nurdyguy **Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at like-dislike.js:144**

Comment: @SébastienTemprado yes, its the error **Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at e (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4)
    at Gb (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4)
    at Function.n.param (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4)
    at Function.ajax (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4)
    at (index):60**

Comment: @Sebas Yes i checked it. plz read my last comment

Comment: Can you add the full html for your page, including the jQuery include.

Comment: @nurdyguy I already have asked a question here with brief details, Plz look at it, [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46831755/like-dislike-increase-in-wrong-order-after-refreshing)

Comment: So in other words this is a duplicate question and should be closed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Like Dislike Increase in Wrong Order after Refreshing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46831755/like-dislike-increase-in-wrong-order-after-refreshing)

Comment: @nurdyguy That is a different question, this is only a part of that issue. i am trying to solve this issue 1st, if this will be done, then i will concentrate on remaining issues So this is the basic thing if ajax Post is not sending data to php. in that question, i have some other issues you can read it. i just referred that question for complete code of my page including php

Answer (score 0):

Data format are depend on which type you want to pass:

> form-data

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append("a", "b");
$.ajax({....
    "data": form
})
```

> x-www-form-urlencode

```
$.ajax({....
    "data": { "a": "b" }
})
```

> raw json body

```
$.ajax({...
    "data": JSON.parse({ "a": "b" })
})
```

Comment: Honestly i am not good at jquery ajax javascript, So i really did not get it. Could you plz correct it in my given code

Comment: What is your server expect to get from your request? which type of server code are you using?

Comment: Also could you add console.log(likes, dislikes) between `var dislikes =  $(this.element).find('.dislikes');` and `$.ajax({` to see the code just work

Comment: Current PHP version: 5.6.8 - I am trying to change the number of likes or dislikes at click event, also want to send data to php for updating database to store the number of likes or dislikes of any comment by users

Comment: Are you using `$_POST['likes']` and `$_POST['dislikes']` to get the data? And once more are your sure the ajax function has been called?
What is the usage of `$('#rating-votes').likeDislike({})` function?

Comment: Yes, I m using `$_POST['likes']` and `$_POST['dislikes']` to get the data. likeDislike function is to increase 1 value to span.likes/span.dislikes text-number. meanwhile, if one person already liked it, now when he will click dislike, the dislike value will be increased but liked value will be decreased. if u want to see that function, i can post it in question but its too long

Comment: if just `$_POST['likes']`, `"data": { "a": "b" }` is the right way, you should check your js code due to your comment on your own post, I think it's other problem more than ajax part

Comment: there are different errors in console  **GET http://localhost/Like-Dislike/bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED**  **GET http://localhost/Like-Dislike/jquery-2.2.3.min.js 404 (Not Found)**  **Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ bootstrap.min.js:6**  **Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at like-dislike.js:144
(anonymous) @ like-dislike.js:144**

Comment: LOL please go to check and fix all the problem first, you seem cannot link with the `jquery-2.2.3.min.js` file so all $ function cannot be used

Comment: i replaced this jquery file with new one, now error type changed. 1 error now **jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at e (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4)
    at Gb (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4)
    at Function.n.param (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4)
    at Function.ajax (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4)
    at (index):61**

Comment: Can i get the solution plz?

Comment: It's hard to debug with just by those error log, are you able to post your full app or all related code to git?

Comment: should i edit the question and update it with all my code including php, and `like-dislike.js file` ?